# I want to center vertically these group-plots but i can't do it

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, groupplots

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,patterns,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric,angles,quotes,bending,petri,decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta,mindmap,trees}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,polar} %




\begin{document}    
\definecolor{aqaqaq}{rgb}{0.6274509803921569,0.6274509803921569,0.6274509803921569}
\definecolor{wqwqwq}{rgb}{0.3764705882352941,0.3764705882352941,0.3764705882352941}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 3},no markers, 
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
enlargelimits=true,
every axis x label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
anchor=west,
},
every axis y label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
anchor=south,
}]
\nextgroupplot[width=7cm,height=6cm,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,xtick={
-6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708,
1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318,7.853981,9.424777
},
xticklabels={
$-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,
$\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $2\pi$, $\frac{5\pi}{2}$, $3\pi$},
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,domain=0:2*pi,samples=40]{cos(deg(x))};
\draw[red,dashed,thick] (3,10) rectangle (5,25);
\node (a2) at (axis cs:pi/6,0.5) {};
\node (b2) at (axis cs:pi/3,0.866) {};
\node (c2) at (axis cs:pi/2,1) {};
\node (d2) at (axis cs:3*pi/4,0.7071) {};
\nextgroupplot[height=4cm,axis lines=none,ymin=-1,xmin=-0.5,ymax=2,xmax=9,x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm]
\addplot coordinates{(0,1)};
\draw[->,color=black] (axis cs:-0.5,0.) -- (axis cs:9.5,0.) node[at end,right]{$x$};
\fill[color=wqwqwq,fill=wqwqwq,pattern=north east lines,pattern color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:-0.5,2.) -- (axis cs:0.,2.) -- (axis cs:0.,0.) -- (axis cs:9.,0.) -- (axis cs:9.,-0.5) -- (axis cs:-0.5,-0.5) -- cycle;
\fill[blue!40!white] (axis cs:4.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:5.5,1);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:-0.5,2.)-- (axis cs:0.,2.);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:0.,2.)-- (axis cs:0.,0.);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:0.,0.)-- (axis cs:9.,0.);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:9.,0.)-- (axis cs:9.,-0.5);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:9.,-0.5)-- (axis cs:-0.5,-0.5);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:-0.5,-0.5)-- (axis cs:-0.5,2.);
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=aqaqaq,decorate,decoration={coil,segment length=6pt,amplitude=3mm}] (axis cs:0.,0.5)-- (axis cs:4.5,0.5);

\nextgroupplot[width=7cm,height=6cm,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,xtick={
-6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708,
1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318,7.853981,9.424777
},
xticklabels={
$-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,
$\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $2\pi$, $\frac{5\pi}{2}$, $3\pi$},
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,domain=0:2*pi,samples=40]{cos(deg(x))};
\draw[red,dashed,thick] (3,10) rectangle (5,25);
\node (a2) at (axis cs:pi/6,0.5) {};
\node (b2) at (axis cs:pi/3,0.866) {};
\node (c2) at (axis cs:pi/2,1) {};
\node (d2) at (axis cs:3*pi/4,0.7071) {};
\nextgroupplot[height=4cm,axis lines=none,ymin=-1,xmin=-0.5,ymax=2,xmax=9,x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm]
\addplot coordinates{(0,1)};
\draw[->,color=black] (axis cs:-0.5,0.) -- (axis cs:9.5,0.) node[at end,right]{$x$};
\fill[color=wqwqwq,fill=wqwqwq,pattern=north east lines,pattern color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:-0.5,2.) -- (axis cs:0.,2.) -- (axis cs:0.,0.) -- (axis cs:9.,0.) -- (axis cs:9.,-0.5) -- (axis cs:-0.5,-0.5) -- cycle;
\fill[blue!40!white] (axis cs:4.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:5.5,1);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:-0.5,2.)-- (axis cs:0.,2.);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:0.,2.)-- (axis cs:0.,0.);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:0.,0.)-- (axis cs:9.,0.);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:9.,0.)-- (axis cs:9.,-0.5);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:9.,-0.5)-- (axis cs:-0.5,-0.5);
\draw [color=wqwqwq] (axis cs:-0.5,-0.5)-- (axis cs:-0.5,2.);
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=aqaqaq,decorate,decoration={coil,segment length=6pt,amplitude=3mm}] (axis cs:0.,0.5)-- (axis cs:4.5,0.5);[![image not centering][1]][1]
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Please complete your code snippet with `\documentclass{...}˙, used package `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` which show your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The whole mess comes, because you are changing the "`height`" of the "right plots"/pics (by changing `height` *and* `y`). Because the plots are just "separated" by `group/horizontal sep` and `group/vertical sep` (the later being the one of interest here) you see the strange alignment which might look random, when only showing two rows of pairs. But you can see the pattern quite clear by just copying a third row of the pair to the `groupplot` environment in the code of the question.

So to fix this you could either

- change the `group/vertical sep` of the right column only
- or use the same `height` in both columns.

Here I show the later case, because this will work also when repeating with 1000 rows, while you have to be set the `vertical sep` very accurately in the first case to still have the same alignment.

For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        patterns,
        pgfplots.groupplots,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % added `compat' level so coordinates can be written without "axis cs:"
        compat=1.11,
        %
        % moved the (same) axis options to styles
        my plot style/.style={
            width=7cm,
            height=6cm,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$\sin x$,
            xtick={
                -6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708,
                1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318,7.853981,9.424777
            },
            xticklabels={
                $-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,
                $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $2\pi$, $\frac{5\pi}{2}$, $3\pi$
            },
            typeset ticklabels with strut,      % <-- added
        },
        my pic style/.style={
            axis lines=none,
%        % --------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % these two lines cause the mess, because they change the height of
%        % of the plot which destroys the alignment
%            height=4cm,
%            y=0.75cm,
%        % (this not really, but because I think you should avoid using them
%        %  I also show another way to "rescale" the width)
%            x=0.75cm,
%        % --------------------------------------------------------------------
            % when not applying `x' any more
            % either you change `xmin' and `xmax' to get the "original" size
            % back or change the `width' of the plot (see below)
            xmin=-0.5,
            xmax=9,
%            % these have to be adapted (see below)
%            ymin=-1,
%            ymax=2,
        % ====================================================================
        % here are the adapted values to make the pics (almost) look the same
        % as before, but this time they are aligned "properly"/as you wanted
            % without using `x' the "`width'" of the plot has to be enlarged
            % (default value = `\axisdefaultwidth' = 240pt)
            width=290pt,
            % set the height to the same value as for the "left side"/the plots
            height=6cm,
            % to now "rescale" the height of the graph, change the Delta of
            % `ymax' and `ymin' until the height of the drawn pic is the same
            % as before. By then adjusting both values by keeping the same Delta
            % you can move the pic so that this fits your needs
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=3,
%%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%%        % or use the original values and just change the `vertical sep' for
%%        % the right column/pics
%%        % (but if you want an \textbf{exact} alignment -- also after 1000 rows
%%        %  -- it will be hard work to find the exact sep via trial and error.
%%        %  Then it would be better to try to calculate the exact vertical sep
%%        %  needed by having a look at the manual who the coordinates are
%%        %  transformed)
%            /pgfplots/group/vertical sep=28mm,
%%        % ====================================================================
        },
    }
    \definecolor{aqaqaq}{rgb}{0.6274509803921569,0.6274509803921569,0.6274509803921569}
    \definecolor{wqwqwq}{rgb}{0.3764705882352941,0.3764705882352941,0.3764705882352941}

    \newcommand*\MyPlot{
        \addplot [smooth,blue,mark=none,domain=0:2*pi,samples=40]{cos(deg(x))};
%    % because of the "new" `compat' level you need to adjust the coordinates
%    % of the rectangle now
%    % (because in the original they are almost not noticeable, I commented it
%    %  here)
%        \draw[red,dashed,thick] (3,10) rectangle (5,25);
    }
    \newcommand*\MyPic{
%        \addplot coordinates{(0,1)};       % <-- not needed
        \draw [->,color=black] (-0.5,0.) -- (9.5,0.)
            node [at end,right] {$x$};
        \fill [color=wqwqwq,fill=wqwqwq,pattern=north east lines,pattern color=wqwqwq]
            (-0.5,2.) -- (0.,2.) -- (0.,0.) -- (9.,0.)
                -- (9.,-0.5) -- (-0.5,-0.5) -- cycle;
        \fill [blue!40!white] (4.5,0) rectangle (5.5,1);
        \draw [color=wqwqwq]  (-0.5,2.)-- (0.,2.);
        \draw [color=wqwqwq]  (0.,2.)-- (0.,0.);
        \draw [color=wqwqwq]  (0.,0.)-- (9.,0.);
        \draw [color=wqwqwq]  (9.,0.)-- (9.,-0.5);
        \draw [color=wqwqwq]  (9.,-0.5)-- (-0.5,-0.5);
        \draw [color=wqwqwq]  (-0.5,-0.5)-- (-0.5,2.);
        \draw [line width=1.6pt,color=aqaqaq,decorate,
            decoration={coil,segment length=6pt,amplitude=3mm}]
                (0.,0.5)-- (4.5,0.5);
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={group size=2 by 3},
            no markers,
            axis y line=center,
            axis x line=middle,
            enlargelimits=true,
            every axis x label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=west,
            },
            every axis y label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=south,
            },
        ]
        % -------------------------------------------
%        % use the pic as first plot instead of the
%        % plot with original settings to check for
%        % the right height
%        \nextgroupplot[
%            xmin=-0.5,
%            xmax=9,
%            ymin=-1,
%            ymax=2,
%            height=4cm,
%            x=0.75cm,
%            y=0.75cm,
%        ]
%            \MyPic
        % ----------
        \nextgroupplot[my plot style]
            \MyPlot
        % -------------------------------------------
        \nextgroupplot[my pic style]
            \MyPic
        \nextgroupplot[my plot style]
            \MyPlot
        \nextgroupplot[my pic style]
            \MyPic
        \nextgroupplot[my plot style]
            \MyPlot
        \nextgroupplot[my pic style]
            \MyPic
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]